# Подключить на сайт ajax и выполнить js после загрузки страници

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, include

Помогите разобраться с вопросом ато гугл не даёт однозначного ответа на мой запрос.

Есть сайт на php
1z Задача в середине страничке в 1м диве подгружать js

```
<script src="/js/myscript.js" type="application/javascript"></script>
```

Но нужно сделать это только после полной прогрузки всей странички.
Например чтобы поисковики это не индексировали и не было нагрузки дополнительной при первоначальной загрузке странички.

И 2я задача как подгрузить также после прогрузки include php странички внутри дива
например `include 'my_include.php';`

Comment: Для первого, загружайте скрипт асинхронно. 2й вопрос взрывает мне мозг :) Уточните что именно пытаетесь сделать

Comment: (Для первого, загружайте скрипт асинхронно) Так я и спрашиваю как сделать это чтобы поисковики не индексировали через ajax . И как его подключить. А 2е у меня есть php обработчик который выводит коменты и мне нужно их подкружать после прогрузки страници и чтобы их поисковики тоже не индексировали.